# Error building Atom from source with Nodejs 7.7.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, fedora, atom-editor

I'm trying to build the Atom editor from source on Fedora. I've already installed all dependencies but I couldn't install Node.js 6.x via nvm (as recommended on Atom's Installation Guide "https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/linux.md"). 
So I installed Node.js via nvm and I got Node.js v7.7.4. Now when I run "script/build" on the atom directory I get this error message:

```
/home/andre/src/atom/script/lib/verify-machine-requirements.js:23
throw new Error(`Atom does not build properly on node v7+. node v${fullVersion} is installed.`)
^

Error: Atom does not build properly on node v7+. node v7.7.4 is installed.
at verifyNode (/home/andre/src/atom/script/lib/verify-machine-requirements.js:23:11)
at module.exports (/home/andre/src/atom/script/lib/verify-machine-requirements.js:10:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/andre/src/atom/script/bootstrap:18:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

I'd like to know how can I install Node.js 6.x and use it when building Atom instead of using Node.js v7.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nvm install 6.x  
nvm use 6.x
```

If still problem,
`nvm uninstall 7.7.4`

Comment: I tried but when I upvote it I get this message : "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."